# Estimation of white noise parameters in Gaussian random walk model

Tags: estimation, normal-distribution, forecasting, random-variable

I want to estimate the parameters (mean , variance ) $e(t)$ for the random walk model
$X (t) = X (t-1) + e(t)$.

(where $e(t)$ is the white noise with a Normal distribution).

By using the fact that the $E(X(t)) = E (X(t-1))$ mean can be easily proven to be zero. Can someone help me to come up with a formal proof for the estimation of std. deviation/variance?

Intuitively my guess is that variance should be defined as : $\sum\frac{(X(t) - X(t-1))^2}{N-1}$

but I don't know how to formally prove it.

Comment: **Hint**: $Y_t = X_t - X_{t-1}$ are iid normal with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So can I just extend it to say that the sum ((X(t) - X(t-1))^2) / (N-1) is an estimate for σ^2?

Comment: Yes. It is the minimum variance unbiased estimate of $\sigma^2$ in this instance.

Comment: I see. Will read more on it.

Answer (score 1):

Do descriptive statistics on the first difference series (what the hint above is suggesting).  The mean of the first diff is an estimate of any trend, and the std dev an estimate of the Gaussian noise in the original series.  Note that if there is a trend present the first diff will not be exactly iid normal zero mean noise.  IF the trend is sizable, continue taking higher order diff series until you get to one with a trend close to zero, then the std dev of that series is your estimate of the noise power in the data.